# How to change default Loading Spinner for Ant Design Pro

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I searched but can't seem to figure out how to change the default loading spinner that is generated with Ant Design Pro V4. I used the generator and ran `npm create umi myApp`. There is a default four circle spinner that I would like to replace with a customized spinner.

The default loader is located here:

```
#/myApp/config/config.ts

...
  dynamicImport: {
    loading: '@/components/PageLoading/index',
  },
...
```

When I modified the `PageLoading/index.tsx` page based on Ant Design's customer spinner documentation. I kept getting this error.

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `LoadableComponent`.
```

*original `PageLoading/index.tsx`*

```js
import { PageLoading } from '@ant-design/pro-layout';

// loading components from code split
// https://umijs.org/plugin/umi-plugin-react.html#dynamicimport
export default PageLoading;
```

*modified `PageLoading/index.tsx`*

```js
import { Spin } from 'antd';
import { LoadingOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const antIcon = <LoadingOutlined style={{ fontSize: 24 }} spin />;

const CustomSpinner = <Spin indicator={antIcon} />

export default CustomSpinner;
```

What do I need to do to make it a `LoadableComponent`? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return value should be a component. Either function or class component.

This would work:

```
import react from 'react';
import { Spin } from 'antd';
import { LoadingOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const antIcon = <LoadingOutlined style={{ fontSize: 24 }} spin />;

// Return value should be component
const CustomSpinner = () => <Spin indicator={antIcon} />

export default CustomSpinner;
```

Comment: Thumbs up Sajad. scootcho, remember to add `import React from 'react'` at the top of the file so the JSX is transpiled. ;)

Comment: @tiomno Yeah that's obvious. I edited the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A new way to doing this. You can define default spin element globally.

```js
//top of app.tsx

import { Spin } from 'antd';
Spin.setDefaultIndicator(<div>Loading</div>);
```

ant design pro referance
https://ant.design/components/spin/#Static-Method